# Solution to system of the form A(y)X=B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I have a system of non-equilibrium equations of the form

$A(y)X=B \quad\quad\quad$  Eq(1)

$X_1=exp(\Sigma_{i=2}^{N}ln(X_i)) \quad\quad\quad$       Eq(2)

Now I have N+1 equations and N+1 unknowns ($X_1$ to $X_N$ & y).

The way I am going about solving this is

```
1>Guess Value of y
2>Calculate X_1 to X_N from eqn1
3>Calculate new X_1 value from eqn2
4>Use the new X_1 and previous X_2:X_N values to find y from eqn1
5>Iterate from step <2> until y_old-y_new < error
```

The initial guess of y is very critical for convergence and I am not able to generalize the solver. Please suggest if there is an issue with the algorithm or any other methods to solve this system

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Simple Case
 $$\begin{matrix}  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
c_1y & c_2 & c_3\\
c_3 & c_4y & c_6\\
c_7 & c_8  & c_9y
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
X_1 \\
X_2 \\
X_3
\end{array} \right)
%
=
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
B_1 \\
B_2 \\
B_3
\end{array} \right)
%
\quad\quad\quad Eq(1)
\end{matrix}$$
$X_1=c_{10}exp(c_{11}ln(X_2)+c_{12}ln(X_3)) \quad\quad \quad\quad Eq(2)$

$c_1$ to $c_{12}$ are constants

$X_i \& y$ are unknowns

Comment: I see TWO equations and no clear indication of what the equations for $X_i$ are for $i>1$. I can not guess what the trail of dots mean. I recommend that you write out the complete set of equations for the smallest value of $N$ with will exhibit the full complexity of the general case.

Comment: Hi Carl, Thanks for the comment. I have edited the question